# Exception : Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm getting the error

> "Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached."

for the above code when I try to delete a record. I have searched a lot for the same but of no use.

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id) {
        tbl_user_master emp = db.tbl_user_masters.Where(val => val.UserId == id).Select(val => new tbl_user_master()
            ).SingleOrDefault();

        db.tbl_user_masters.DeleteOnSubmit(emp);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
    }
```

i expect the preferred row to be deleted rather than bringing me again to the code every time.

Answer (score 1):

```
tbl_user_master emp = db.tbl_user_masters.Where(val => val.UserId == id).Select(val => val 
            ).SingleOrDefault();
```

**This helped me to solve the code**

**Thank you**

Comment: You shouldn't need `.Select(val => val)`. You can just do `.Where(...).SingleOrDefault()`. Or even `.SingleOrDefault(v => c.UserId = id)`;

Answer (score 0):

How to use and apply the [DeleteOnSubmit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.table-1.deleteonsubmit?view=netframework-4.8) to your application with entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the object like this

```
tbl_user_master emp = db.tbl_user_masters.SingleOrDefault(val => val.UserId == id);
```

You were getting a new `tbl_user_masters` object from select and that object was not something EF tracks.